# Bubble Sort not working correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I've been working on this for awhile and I have tried multiple different algorithms for the bubble sort that I have found online but none of them are working properly for me and I'm pretty close to giving up, but this is due tomorrow night. I'd really appreciate if someone could point out where im going wrong. I dont really understand this algorithm with the bool so ill try to find what i was trying before and edit it in

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void GetInfo(int[], int&);
void BubbleSort(int[], int);
void BinarySearch(int[], int);

int main()
{
    int size;
    int array[500];
    GetInfo(array, size);
    BubbleSort(array, size);
    BinarySearch(array, size);
    return 0;
}

void GetInfo(int array[], int& size)
{
    cout << "Enter the number of naturals: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Enter the natural numbers to sort: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }

}

void BubbleSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int temp;
    bool check = true;
    int end = 0;
    while(check)
    {
        end++;
        check = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < size - end; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]) //I'm positive this part is correct
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = temp;
                check = true;
            }
        }

    }
       cout << endl << "Numbers sorted in ascending order: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << ' ';
    }
}

void BinarySearch(int array[], int size) //this doesnt work properly atm but 
{                                        //should be good when the sort works
    int index;
    int top = size - 1;
    int bottom = 0;
    int middle = (top) / 2;
    bool found = false;
    int target;

    cout << endl << "Enter the number to search: ";

    cin >> target;

    while (found == false)
    {
        if (target > array[middle])
        {
            bottom = middle + 1 ;
            middle = ((top - bottom)/2) + bottom;
        }
        else if (target < array[middle])
        {
            top = middle - 1;
            middle = ((top - bottom)/2) + bottom;
        }
        else
        {
            found = true;
            index = middle;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number " << target << " is found in position " << index << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes bubble sort is what's wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You might meant to swap a[i] with a[i+1] while you actually swapped a[size+1]

Comment: Thanks, i realised that right after posting. It works now but it is taking the highest value, replacing with a 0 and putting it at the front. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: I changed for(int i = 0; i < size - end; i++) to for(int i = 0; i < size - 1 - end; i++). Thanks for your help, I was stuck on that for way too long!

Comment: @Stw59 It's nice you can review your code 2nd time and find out the problem now. A solid step towards a real programmer. Gratz

Answer (score 1):

These lines are wrong:

```
            array[i] = array[size+1];
            array[size+1] = temp;
```

You need:

```
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = temp;
```

Comment: Thanks, i realised that right after posting. It works now but it is taking the highest value, replacing with a 0 and putting it at the front. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: I changed for(int i = 0; i < size - end; i++) to for(int i = 0; i < size - 1 - end; i++). Thanks for your help, I was stuck on that for way too long!

Comment: That is not correct though. `for(int i = 0; i < size - end; i++)` is correct. See working code at http://ideone.com/1Z2wHd.